# Efficiently read scribed text on credit cards with an ocr api

Tags: java, android, sdk, card.io

Since various OCR Api's like `Tesseract` ,`Blink` `ocr` and `abby fine reader` dont do much with scribed text reading.If there is any good opensource `OCR` API or SDK (like a jar ) which can be used to read scribed card text in android or java and also I found `card.io` SDK for android.Is it good enough though.
Please explain with code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a perfect match,an `SDK` called `card.io` and it comes for both android and ios versions and it's free I guess.So I am going to try it.
Mainly I want to make it read the scribed text on cards.
The demo published on their site [card.io](https://www.card.io/) seems to be promising.Though the sdk just scans the info and you have to process it to a gateway.